# Why does coveralls / kcov calculate incorrect code coverage statistics for Rust programs?

Tags: rust, code-coverage

**EDIT: I've replaced this question with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32521800/1667955). I will delete this question soon. Thanks for the feedback.**

I've setup code coverage in my Rust project, by using [travis ci](https://travis-ci.org/mbrt/ruplicity) and [coveralls](https://coveralls.io/github/mbrt/ruplicity?branch=master). To do this I've used [travis-cargo](https://github.com/huonw/travis-cargo) following its documentation. This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: rust
sudo: required

before_script:
  - pip install 'travis-cargo<0.2' --user && export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

rust:
  - stable
  - beta
  - nightly

script:
  - cargo test

after_success:
  - travis-cargo coveralls
```

However I'm facing a strange high coverage. Some files in the project gets a 100% coverage, even if they are actually not covered at all! Consider for example [this file](https://coveralls.io/builds/3532092/source?filename=src%2Fcollections%2Fmod.rs); the only test it contains is a dummy one:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
    }
}
```

And the reported coverage is 100%. As you can see by coverage highlights in the coveralls page, all the source code lines are ignored, except the dummy test function.

What is the problem here? Maybe test binaries strip down unused functions and `kcov` cannot see them?

Comment: [*Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem <...> include the code in your question itself*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve), preferably one that doesn't require an answerer to create a project that runs in Travis CI.

Comment: @Shepmaster I thought it was simpler to use my project, since travis-ci is configured and the results are visible in the web page. However it is not MCVE. In case of a minimal example, I'd have to link to a tutorial on how to setup `kcov` locally, I suppose. What do you think?

Comment: Please add the Cargo.toml at least. Without knowing if you have debug-symbols on, we cannot outrule this as possible problem source.

Comment: @llogiq I've reproduced the problem locally. I'll post a new question as soon as I get a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Why not just [edit] this question?

Comment: @Shepmaster I thought a complete rewrite implies a new question. Doesn't it?

Comment: @brt only if it invalidates existing answers. Otherwise it's just a step along the journey to a really good question. Besides, the main question is the same, you just have a much better way of asking it now. ^_^

Comment: @brt: well, the new question is much better; however I advise you to avoid deleting your own questions too often, as it could trigger a question-ban. One is fine of course, just avoid doing it for some time now :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ok, I'll simply mark this question as duplicate.